# Escape awk $ in shell function of bashrc

Tags: awk, bash

I have a command that gets the next ID of a table from a pool of sql files, now I am trying to put this command as an alias in ~/.bashrc using a shell function, but I did not figure out how to escape `$` so it gets to awk and not replaced by bash, here's the code in `.bashrc`:

```
function nextval () {
    grep 'INSERT INTO \""$1"\"' *.sql | \
    awk '{print $6}' | \
    cut -c 2- | \
    awk -F "," '{print $1}' | \
    sort -n | \
    tail -n 1 | \
    awk '{print $0+1}'
}

alias nextval=nextval
```

Usage: `# nextval tablename`

Escaping with `\$` I get an the error: `awk: backslash not last character on line`.
The `$` is not inside double quotes, so why bash is replacing it ?

Comment: Don't you mix up single and double quotes in the `grep` command? I don't understand why you surround `$1` with double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: You don't need an escape (`\ `) after a pipe symbol (`|`) at the end of a line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the part you really need to change is this

```
'INSERT INTO \""$1"\"'
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO \"$1\""
```

Comment: Accepted even if I like @ed-morton 's awk solution, just because this solves the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

@konsolebox answered your question but also you could write the function without so many tools and pipes, e.g.:

```
function nextval () {
    awk -v tbl="$1" '
        $0 ~ "INSERT INTO \"" tbl "\"" {
            split( substr($6,2), a, /,/ )
            val = ( ((val == "") || (a[1] > val)) ? a[1] : val)
        }
        END { print val+1 }
    ' *.sql
}
```

It's hard to tell if the above is 100% correct without any sample input or expected output to test it against but it should be close.

Comment: +1 for this solution, it works as expected. By the way I was expecting criticism for using so many tools (even if they do the job), as I am not that expert with awk :), thanks